# adding a new page to precompiled website

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I've been tasked with editing and updating a precompiled website written in c#. Unfortunately I have little knowledge or experience with the language nor do I have the source code for the website.

I've managed to edit the .dll file by using dotPeek to decompile the files then editing and recompiling them in Visual Studio before copy-pasting the new .dll files back into the bin of the original project.

I've been trying to add a new page by basicly reworking another page of the same website but whenever I try to build the website it gives me this error.

> Could not load type 'Contacts' from assembly 'App_Web_dvy2uzvm, 
>   Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I did add a cs to the updated dll with the proper name but it seems unable to access it and I haven't been able to track down any information online. I'm probably just googling the wrong questions though.

This is the bit of code which I believe contains the issue.

```
<%@ page language="C#" masterpagefile="~/SampleMaster.master"
 autoeventwireup="true" inherits="Contacts, App_Web_dvy2uzvm" title="Untitled Page" %>
```

Any sort of help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need the source code to recompile with the new page added. That's the way it's meant to work, and is why you're finding it difficult to find answers.

Comment: So you're saying that nothing can be done? What if I were to only edit the currently available pages to squeeze everything in?

Comment: Or a better yet, what source files do I need exactly? I can get all the sources files held in the dll files. If it's something that's needed from a new website project, would it be possible for me to start a new website project then manually adding all the current site's code to new pages and then simply compiling that?

Comment: Visual Studio has a Solution file which references one or more projects. When you compile that, you get the DLL file(s) and this is what you deploy to your server. The projects contain references to source files and this is where you need to add the new page(s). You can run it locally to test, and when satisfied you can publish it which will give you the new version of the DLLs to put on your server

Comment: So the Solution file references the projects which are to become your DLL files. If I were to decompile all the dll files that the website uses and add their references again would it work with the original project file or should I copy all the pages over to a new Website project to get a new Solution file then reference from there?

Comment: You said you had the source files. They should be in a project file, contained within a visual studio solution file. Decompiling DLLs is a last resort and requires experience to get working like you are trying to do

Comment: I said I don't have the source files. I can only decompile the DLL files I have to get the source files contained within. 

Unfortunately the last resort is the only one available and the only experience I can access is that of helpful souls like yourself. I haven't even worked with Visual Studios or c# before this project came along. 
I know java and a smattering of html, sql and such but that's the limit of my knowledge
 
If there's  a way to get this project working I'll do it so please, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm already making some progress. I've made use of the source files generated by the decompiled dll to add the reference. Now it's a new error System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.